# MUI 5 sx not working correctly with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Simple question. Why this one works:

```
const heroText = {
  height: 400,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
}

<Grid item sx={heroText}>Some text</Grid>
```

And this one will give you the Typescript error ("No overload matches this call."):

```
const heroText = {
  height: 400,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  flexDirection: "column",
}

<Grid item sx={heroText}>Some text</Grid>
```

If you do not believe me that just adding the `flexDirection: "column"` will produce Typescript error, you can try it for yourself.

I am working with new MUI 5, React and Typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inferred type for `flexDirection` on your `heroText` object is `string` but the `sx` prop is expecting something more specific (a string union of "column" | "column-reverse" | "row" | "row-reverse", etc...)

The preferred solution here is probably to add a type for `heroText`:

```
const heroText: SxProps = {
  height: 400,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  flexDirection: "column",
}

<Grid item sx={heroText}>Some text</Grid>
```

Another solution could be to assert a more specific type for `flexDirection` with `as const`

```
const heroText = {
  height: 400,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  flexDirection: "column" as const,
}

<Grid item sx={heroText}>Some text</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, and thanks for the answer. I already found this second solution ("as const") on Material UI website, and that actually SOLVED the problem with Typescript, but now I get "Failed to compile" error. Now I googling how to fix this new error.

Comment: As a newcomer to StackOverflow, this is a nice answer @aaron-becker!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`const assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to cast the value to an object literal. This will prevent the value of each property from being widen (e.g. The type of display is `"flex"` instead of `string` which is not a valid value of the `display`):

```
const heroText = {
  height: 400,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
} as const
```

Another solution is to declare the `SxProp` type, this is a bit longer but has the advantage of giving you intellisense when setting the value:

```
import { SxProps } from '@mui/system';

const sx: SxProps = {
  height: 400,
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'column',
};
```

Comment: I get this error using SxProps
`The SxProps can be either object or function

Cannot use SxProps as a type because it is an any-typed value. Type SxProps properly, so it is no longer any-typed, to use it as an annotation.Flow(value-as-type)`